# Cordova Sqlite Database Error when Upgrading to 64 Bit

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, 64-bit, x86-64

Due to the recent update from Google Play Store, advising that all apps must now be 64 bit Compliant to be served by the Play Store, I have attempted to update our Cordova Android application to 64 bit.

Following, Google's advice, we have determined that there is only one of our cordova plugins that is not 64 Bit Compliant. However, this is causing painful issues.

The plugin in question, was the `cordova-sqlcipher-adapter`. We relied on this to encrypt our SQLite databases and to serve the databases to the application. We have now removed the reliance on this plugin for the encryption aspect. Therefore, it frees us up to upgrade to 64 bit.

When attempting to upgrade this, we realised that this plugin is built upon another plugin, `cordova-sqlite-storage` which handles the opening databases and executing commands. Therefore, to simplify things, we removed the `cordova-sqlcipher-adapter` and added the `cordova-sqlite-storage` plugin to ensure no issues were raised from the cipher aspect.

When running the application, using the new plugin, at a 64 bit compliant version, the app errors when attempting to run queries on one of the databases.

The error returned is:

`Error: a statement error callback did not return false: no such table: RNM_Setting (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT s.Value AS [Value] FROM <MYTABLE> s WHERE s.[Key] = <PARAM>`

We have tried different versions but always end up with the same issue and cannot find another way to interact with SQLite databases from a Cordova Android Application.

We have confirmed that the database in question exists in the correct directory and is populated with data and the table in question. We have even pulled the database out and run the exact query on it which succeeds so it cannot be a database issue.

The code used to open the database is:

```js
SQLiteWrapper.prototype.OpenDatabase = function () {
    var self = this;

    if (this.db === null && this.hasSqlite) {
        this.db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: this.dbName, iosDatabaseLocation: 'Documents' });
    }
};

this.GetSettingValue = function (settingKey, successCallback, failCallback) {
    var self = this;
    try {
        var sql = ["SELECT ",
                    "   s.Value AS [Value] ",
                    "FROM ",
                    "   <MYTABLE> s ",
                    "WHERE ",
                    "   s.[Key] = ? "];
        sql = sql.join("");
        var params = [settingKey];

        this.sql.GetSingleItem(sql, params, this.ReadSettingFromDb, successCallback, fail);
    } catch (e) {
        fail(e);
    }

    function fail(e) {
        self.CallbackError(failCallback, "GetSettingValue", e);
    };
}

SQLiteWrapper.prototype.GetSingleItem = function (sql, params, rowRead, successCallback, failCallback) {
    var self = this;
    try {
        this.OpenDatabase();
        this.db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql(sql, params, executeSuccess, executeFail);
        }, function (e) {
            fail(e);
        });

        function executeSuccess(tx, rs) {
            var item = null;
            try {
                if (rs.rows.length > 0) {
                    var row = rs.rows.item(0);
                    item = rowRead(row);
                }
                successCallback(item);
            } catch (e) {
                fail(e);
            }
        }

        function executeFail(tx, e) {
            fail(e);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        fail(e);
    }

    function fail(e) {
        self.CallbackError(failCallback, "GetSingleItem", e);
    }
};

this.ReadSettingFromDb = function (row) {
    return row.Value;
};
```

We are at a bit of a loss now as to how to interact with a SQLite database in a 64 Bit Compliant way. Any help to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you've used a cipher-driver before, you either need to de-crypt the database or start over with a new one database. There might be a table `RNM_Setting`, but without decryption it behaves as if it would not exist. Ever tried opening that file on a computer with "DB Browser for SQLite" ?

Besides, your reasoning concerning 64 bit does not make much sense, simply because [android-database-sqlcipher-ndk.jar](https://github.com/brodybits/cordova-sqlcipher-adapter/blob/latest/src/android/libs/android-database-sqlcipher-ndk.jar) has an `arm64-v8a/libsqlcipher.so`.

Comment: Sorry I missed that info, so I do have a database there without the encryption so that the encryption is not an issue

Comment: @DaRoGa if you've already released it, then there are databases with encryption. removing the SqlCipher wasn't even required, because it certainly supports 64 bits since at least 3 months.

Comment: I understand that it is meant to work with 64 bit, however, my issue is that it isn't and I am asking for help to find out why